# Problemns connecting Spring to Active Directory

Tags: spring, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to connect to my company's active diretory to create an appplication capable of adding, updating and removing users from it, I configured may LdapContextSource with all the information my collegue who created de AD environment but when I try to do a simple search it doesn't work and give me this error:
`org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 8 - BindSimple: Transport encryption required.]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 8 - BindSimple: Transport encryption required.]`

Here is my simple code:

```
 public User getUserByLogin(String login) {
    LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
    try {
        contextSource.setUrl("secret");
        contextSource.setBase("secret");
        contextSource.setUserDn("secret");
        contextSource.setPassword("secret");
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
        User user = ldapTemplate.findOne(query().where("uid").is(login), User.class);
        return user;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

May be relevant to let you guys to know that we're using GSS-API

Thanks in advance, hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that transport encryption is required -- this generally means you need to change the LDAP server URI from ldap://server.domain.gTLD to ldaps://server.domain.gTLD *but* since few LDAP servers use certs issued from a public certificate authority (CA), you'll also need to set up the certificate trust. I use a private CA to sign all certificates, so can import the CA public key into the Java truststore.